# sql Traversing parent child

Tags: sql-server, hierarchical

I am dealing with some hierarchical data in the following form:

```
Level      Parent    PrimaryKey    LevelDepth    RevenuePct
Total       NULL     2786f8161           0           100
US          Total    33f254b0f           1           60
UK          Total    462adbba            1           25
Asia        Total    5322678b3           1           15
Mobile       US      75b72bdf1           2           10
Laptop       US      813784df5           2           10
PC           US      9550f97c            2           15
Consulting   US      a44ae3ef8           2           25
Mobile       UK      ace663d07           2           10
Laptop       UK      b373e61c            2           8
PC           UK      ca590ef44           2           7
Mobile      Asia     d136f267e           2           15
```

and I want it to be displayed in following form:

```
Breakup                      Revenue [%]
Total                           100
    US                           60
            Mobile               10
            Laptop               10
            PC                   15
            Consulting           25
    UK                           25
            Mobile               10
            Laptop                8
            PC                    7
    Asia                         15
            Mobile               15
```

The actual problem has 6-7 level of nesting.

I am relatively new to the field and am trying to use CTE but am having issue with join condition since the child entries repeat in different parents (i.e. I have mobile category for US, UK etc...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that. `Path` column is used for sorting - you should probably instead of \ concatenate fixed-width `level` to produce path. Query works by recursively calling cte part until no row satisfies join condition between first part of cte (expressed as `cte` in second part after union all) and table1.

```
; with cte as (
  select level, parent, revenuepct, leveldepth, cast (level as varchar(1000)) Path
    from table1
   where parent is null
  union all
  select a.level, a.parent, a.revenuepct, a.leveldepth, cast (path + '\' + a.level as varchar(1000))
    from table1 a
   inner join cte
      on a.parent = cte.level
)
-- Simple indentation
select space(leveldepth * 4) + level as Breakup, 
       revenuepct as [revenue %]
  from cte
 order by path
-- Max recursive calls, 0 = unlimited
option (maxrecursion 10)
```

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c6d6/6).

[And here is a link to article on recursive cte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: ..Thank you for your response. I came up with something similar but the query will fail if we go another level down for example If we have child entities ModelA, ModelB and ModelC for Mobile phones in US and UK.

Comment: @user1512829 You need to add option (maxrecursion 0), please check my updated answer.